# Is nested select statement better than where statement?

Tags: sql

I want to speedup my queries.
I was wondering if there is any performance difference in the following queries.

method #1:

```
select 
   *
from 
   t0, t1
where 
   t0.a = X
   and t0.b = t1.b
```

method #2:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   (select * from t0 where t0.a = X) as t0', t1
where
   t0'.b=t1.b;
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all using comma join syntax should be avoided:

```
select    *
from    t0, t1
where    t0.a = X
   and t0.b = t1.b

=>
select    *
from t0
join t1
  on t0.a = X
 and t0.b = t1.b;
```

Second modern query optimizers perfrom predicate pushdown so both your queries are equivalent.

[10 Cool SQL Optimisations That do not Depend on the Cost Model by Lukas Eder](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/#top10)

Comment: Is there any reason that the comma join syntax should be avoided?

Comment: @Shabnam It is old syntax, there is really no reason to use it.Plus outer joins are really hard to follow with `(+)=` or `(*)=` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should write your query as:

```
select *
from t0 join
     t1
     on t0.b = t1.b
where t0.a = X;
```

Using modern, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, however, will not affect the performance of the query.

For better performance, you want an index on `t0(a, b)` and `t1(b)`.